# AWS Cron Schedule pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scenebuilder, rules, aws-event-bridge

I want to run my AWS Lambda from 3PM EST to 4:05 PM EST in every 13 mins interval from Monday to Friday. I've used this expression as scheduled pattern Amazon EventBridge Rules in my trigger:

```
  0/13      20         ?            *         MON-FRI        *
Minutes   Hours   Day of Month    Month     Day of Week    Year
```

It runs from 3pm to 4 PM in 13 mins interval and stops at 3:52 PM but I want to run one more time at 4:05 PM. How can I change the Hour pattern to achieve this?

I tried hour as 20-21 but this only takes a full hour not first 5 min after 4 pm. My expectation is to change the hour so it take 4:05 PM schedule as per 13 min interval time.

Comment: Maybe create a separate rule that is triggered only once at 4:05 PM specifically.

Comment: That's an option for sure but we need to create a new one only for one run. I was trying to avoid it. Is there any way to start the Job at 3pm and next run 6 times in 13 mins interval?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it in a single cron expression you need to use more than one cron expression to handle exception cases.

- `0/13 20 ? * MON-FRI *` -> 2000, 2013, 2026, 2039, 2052
- `5  ? * MON-FRI *`.     -> 2105